# javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using com.emc.object.s3. I am trying to list all the key in a S3 bucket, but when I call the listObjects method in S3Client, it raises the following error.

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been
> found on module path or classpath. - with linked exception:
> [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
> Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or
> classpath.
> with linked exception:
> [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:115)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
> ...
> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API
> has not been found on module path or classpath.
> with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]    at
> javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:232)  at
> javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:375)     at
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)  at
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)  at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:196)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:188)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:140)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:123)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
> ... 96 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:72)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
> at
> javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
> at
> javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
> at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:230)
> ... 104 more

I tried to add jaxb to build.gradle, but it doesn't help.

```
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0-b170127.1453'
    implementation 'javax.activation:activation:1.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
```

listing method

```
    public void list() {
        ListObjectsResult objectListing = s3client.listObjects(nBucket);//this line causing the error

        for (S3Object objectSummary : objectListing.getObjects()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                        "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
        }

    }
```

How can I fix the problem? Alternatively, any other methods to list all keys?

Comment: Try to implement to compile and  `jaxb-runtime` to  `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0`

Comment: @Jilliss still not work

Comment: Whether the error message is different  `jaxb-runtime:2.3.0 ` contain  `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception/43574427?r=Saves_UserSavesList#43574427      `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0` change to  `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe [AWS SDK for Java v2 S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html). The official AWS SDK for Java V2 S3Client works perfectly in a Spring BOOT web project. Using the AWS Java **S3Client**, you can avoid all of these dependency issues.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.list_objects.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import java.util.List;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.list_objects.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class ListObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket from which objects are read. \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        listBucketObjects(s3, bucketName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.list_objects.main]
    public static void listBucketObjects(S3Client s3, String bucketName ) {

        try {
            ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
            List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();
            for (S3Object myValue : objects) {
                System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
                System.out.print("\n The object is " + calKb(myValue.size()) + " KBs");
                System.out.print("\n The owner is " + myValue.owner());
            }

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    //convert bytes to kbs.
    private static long calKb(Long val) {
        return val/1024;
    }
   // snippet-end:[s3.java2.list_objects.main]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s always better to use an official AWS SDK instead of 3rd party APIs.

Comment: This can go as a comment!!

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to comment. :D